# case statement to group individuals returns wrong answer

Tags: sql

converting Oracle sql to Tsql and this code originally had floor in it, which my sql server studio thinks is wrong, so I took it out - I feel like this should work.  It runs fine - but regardless of the date of birth, it always returns '18 and over' which is not correct. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I did try putting floor back in - but it didn't like it.

```
,case 

when (cast(fed.ADT_ARRIVAL_date - pat.BIRTH_DATE as int))  < 29
    then '0 to 28 days' 
when (cast(fed.ADT_ARRIVAL_date - pat.BIRTH_DATE as int)>=29 
    and cast(fed.ADT_ARRIVAL_date - pat.BIRTH_DATE as int) <4 )
    then '29 days to 3 years' 
when (cast(fed.ADT_ARRIVAL_date - pat.BIRTH_DATE as int)>=4 
    and cast(fed.ADT_ARRIVAL_date - pat.BIRTH_DATE as int)<6 )
    then '4 to 5 years' 

when (cast(fed.ADT_ARRIVAL_date - pat.BIRTH_DATE as int) >=6 
    and cast(fed.ADT_ARRIVAL_date - pat.BIRTH_DATE as int) <11 )
    then '6 to 10 years'
when (cast(fed.ADT_ARRIVAL_date - pat.BIRTH_DATE as int) >=11 
    and cast(fed.ADT_ARRIVAL_date - pat.BIRTH_DATE as int) <14 )
    then '11 to 13 years' 

when ( cast(fed.ADT_ARRIVAL_date - pat.BIRTH_DATE as int)>=14 
    and cast(fed.ADT_ARRIVAL_date - pat.BIRTH_DATE as int) <18  )
    then '14 to 17 years' 
when cast(fed.ADT_ARRIVAL_date - pat.BIRTH_DATE as int) >=18 
then '18 and above'     
else NULL
end age
```

I am wanting it to group these individuals into buckets based on their age, at the time of arrival,

Comment: TSQL does have a `floor()` function. Maybe it takes different arguments? Can't remember off top of my head. Returning the difference value in another column would have clued you in that the difference values are not years. Except for the one weird case, the `case` expression is not where the problem lies. Calculation of age is also a bit trickier than subtraction anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I guess correctly, you are looking for calculate date differences between 2 dates where there are some Syntax issue considering MSSQL Server. In MSSQL Server, you can calculate date differences as below-

```
CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DD,fed.ADT_ARRIVAL_date,pat.BIRTH_DATE) < 29
    -- Do not required CAST AS INT as it by default return INT
    .....
END
```

You have also issue with checking values as I found you are checking the same value >=29 AND < 4 !! this can not be TRUE any time. Also I am confused about your distribution of ages between Days to Year where as all values you are checking between 4 to 29. Anyway I hope those all are test data and you can get your desired output through the correct DATEDIFF method for MSSQL Server.